# How to install Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard in VMWare?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I'm pretty new to Macs and would like to familiarize myself with the latest Mac OS. How do I install [Mac OS X 10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) in [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware)? Is it possible without a lot of hacking around with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple licensing does not allow for the virtualization of Mac OS X Client on any hardware and only allows for the virtualization of [Mac OS X Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Server) on Apple hardware. Anything else is in violation of the license agreement.

Comment: The passage of time has rendered this answer incorrect - Since Lion, 10.7 (July 2011) it is perfectly acceptable to install OS X as a VM - **so long as that VM is running on Apple hardware**

Answer (score 2):

No. Virtualization of Snow Leopard (Client) is not officially supported/allowed by any virtualization solution. (Well, at least for Leopard there were some unofficial hacks to install it with VMware Fusion but I never bothered...)

Apple does only allow virtualization of Snow Leopard **Server** on a **Mac** host. It is e.g. supported as a guest in VMware Fusion 3. But that won't help you.

Comment: Interesting - as Apple now offers MAc-Minis running Server .. should I put my pinky to my mouth and go "muahahaha" ??

Comment: You can emulate it on plain VMware workstation with "hacks". The only involvement with Fusion is that you need the VMware tools from Fusion (because it is the only officially supported way of emulating Mac on Mac), but that's about it.