# What virtualization software do I need to run Mac OS X on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard in VMWare?](https://superuser.com/questions/65840/how-to-install-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-in-vmware)

I've checked numerous websites, but all of them seem to suggest running Windows on Mac. I have Windows 7 and I need to access Mac OS X. Buying Mac or installing Mac OS on a physical system aren't options for me.
I know Mac OS X Server Snow Leopard can be virtualized, but can't find it described in Parallels or VmWare. Which product of those companies or others can be used for virtualization in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With legalities aside, you're after [PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/). What you do with it is your responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

PearPC is a PPC emulator. But you can virtualize Snow Leopard with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
More information [here](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows).

Comment: You will need a few other tweaks to get it working.  You need a hackintosh-friendly OSX installation source for starters, and I believe you need a CPU that supports hardware-accelerated virtualization.  Here's a link to the full set of instructions: http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows

I'm not going to undermine reg by posting this as an answer.  Reg beat me to the punch with Virtualbox, so I'm just giving you the rest of the information you'll need.

Comment: Hi TuxRug (nice name by the way!), thanks for improving the information. Funny that I actually added a link to this very article just before I saw your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.6 is supported for VirtualBox VMs: http://virtualbox.org

http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows