# Can we install (Mac + iPhone SDK 4.1) using vmware (Virtual Machine)?

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard in VMWare?](https://superuser.com/questions/65840/how-to-install-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-in-vmware)

Can we install (Mac + iPhone SDK 4.1) using vmware (Virtual Machine)?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you're really not supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No.

Yes it is possible, but no it is not legal (breaking the EULA) so we can not help you here.

Answer (score 1):

In short: no, you can't. You need Mac OS X to use xcode, and you are only allowed to install it to Apple computers.