# How to virtualize Lion or Mac Server in Windows 7 on iMac?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, imac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard in VMWare?](https://superuser.com/questions/65840/how-to-install-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-in-vmware)

Two questions:

1. How do I run Mac OS X Lion in Windows 7 on my iMac? I know it is legal to virtualize Lion and Mac Server but I am not sure whether I can do it from Windows on Apple hardware.
2. I have installed Windows 7 via Boot Camp on my iMac; can I open Mac partitions from Windows 7 using VMware Workstation?

I can do the same from OS X and open up Windows 7 partitions using Fusion.

Comment: Wait... *what?!?!*  You have an iMac, running Windows, and you want to VM Mac OS X on *that?!?!*  Why not just rebuild the system with Lion, and make the Windows machine your VM?

Comment: [why-would-anyone-ever-do-this]

Comment: well i will only use mac osx to build apps for ios devices so my primary OS will be windows 7 for all other things , so putting windows on vm means running two OSes  all the time, so i would like to run lion when i need to

is there any solution to my specific problem